# the documentation for sonarqube 3.7.4 is no more online

Tags: sonarqube, documentation

Where could I find the documentation for sonarqube 3.7.4 ?

I tried the following links : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation
and 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation+for+previous+versions
for the older versions

Comment: I highly recommend to upgrade to a newer version... I mean this is version is at least 3 years old ( much older for sure) and we had 2 LTS In the mean time. And the third one is on its way normally

Comment: Thx Simon.
But why upgrading when I just need the 3.7.4 web api documentation ?

Comment: i am not sure in what environment you are working, and what is your usage of sonar... for my work (java) i basically want to have all the issues regarding Java8 - furthermore i want to use some plugins which are not support with versions pre 5.6 -> on the side to performance improvements -> using Java through out the whole "sonarqube" instead of "rails" (not sure what it was before) - are for me the reason to use an up to date version of sonarqube. Even the web api improved :D

Comment: We are using for a cobol project ; several million lines of code.
We have no plans to change version.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of 3.7.4 is not available anymore since 3.7.4 was released 3.5 years ago (as Simon pointed).

You really should upgrade to latest LTS (5.6.6).

If you are looking for the javadoc it's still available here : http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/3.7.4/apidocs/

Comment: Well, Thx for your answer.
But the 3.7.4 version works well, and I just need the documentation about the web api.